# Automation Testing Utility(ATU reporting) not working with multiple test in testng.xml

Tags: selenium-webdriver, testng, utility

I am fan of [ATU(Automation testing utility)](http://automationtestingutilities.blogspot.in/p/reporting.html) reporting tool and loved the html report.

Here I need your help with html report generated by ATU with multiple test in testng.xml file.

In my testng.xml file I have 3-4 test as shown in below testng.xml file.

1st test. Receptionist login, registration, search, edit test.

2nd test. Receptionist logout (created different test because testng.xml don't allow to call same class in same test)

3rd test. Doctor login, search task, and create case.

```
<suite name="AUT Test" verbose="1">
    <listeners>
        <listener class-name="atu.testng.reports.listeners.ATUReportsListener"></listener>
        <listener class-name="atu.testng.reports.listeners.ConfigurationListener"></listener>
        <listener class-name="atu.testng.reports.listeners.MethodListener"></listener>
    </listeners>

    <test name="Sanity One">
        <parameter name="url" value="URL" />

        <parameter name="registrationCount" value="2" />

        <groups>
            <run>
                <include name="sanityregression" />
            </run>
        </groups>

        <classes>
            <class name="com.LoginTest">
                           <parameter name="role" value="Receptionist" />
                <methods>
                    <include name="Login" />
                </methods>
            </class>            
            <class name="com.RegistrationTest" />
            <class name="com.SearchTest" />
            <class name="com.ViewProfileTest" />
            <class name="com.EditTest" />
        </classes>
    </test>

<test name="Sanity Method Logout"> 
        <classes>
           <class name="com.LoginTest" >
              <methods>
                <include name="Logoff" />
              </methods>
            </class>
        </classes>        
    </test>

    <test name="Sanity for doctor"> 
        <classes>
           <class name="com.LoginTest" >
            <parameter name="role" value="Doctor" />    
              <methods>
                <include name="Login" />
              </methods>
            </class>

            <class name="com.SearchDoctorTask" />
            <class name="com.CreateCaseTest" />
        </classes>        
    </test>
```

Now my problem is when I have multiple test in testng.xml file then ATU html report is created only for last test i.e 3rd while first two test report is not created or deleted.

How I will create ATU html report for all the test in testng.xml.

Comment: Hi, did you get any solution for this? If yes, it would be better to provide solution over here.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
suite name="abcd" parallel="tests"
```